# How to make call to external api from nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hi all I have to develop a utility which makes a call to external API with different parameters, for example, I have an array val which has 100 value val= ['we23','22ww', 'gh22'....n] and URL: www.google.com so one by one I have to append value from val to the URL, first api= www.google.com/we23, second api= www.google.com/22ww and make an External API hit and then store the response in database. so what is the most efficient way to do it? and links to working examples would be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A very simple example express app using the Fetch API:

```js
const express = require('express')
const fetch = require('node-fetch')
const app = express()

// This sets up a route to localhost:3000/random and goes off and hits
// cat-fact.herokuapp.com/facts/random
app.get('/:apiRoute', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { apiRoute } = req.params
    const apiResponse = await fetch(
      'https://cat-fact.herokuapp.com/facts/' + apiRoute
    )
    const apiResponseJson = await apiResponse.json()
    // await db.collection('collection').insertOne(apiResponseJson)
    console.log(apiResponseJson)
    res.send('Done – check console log')
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
    res.status(500).send('Something went wrong')
  }
})

app.listen(3000, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port 3000!`))
```

Visit http://localhost:3000/random

Comment: Hi, Andy thank you for your reply. please confirm one thing, the fetch function used above is from the node-fetch package?

Comment: Moreover when I execute the above code with node- fetch package I am getting `Promise { <pending>}` in apiResponse

Comment: node-fetch will work fine :) Apologies - I missed out an `await` before `apiResponse.json()`. Edited my answer with a working API to test with as well.

Comment: Sweet, glad it worked. Don't forget to mark as solved if possible so I get that glorious green tick ;)

Comment: Note: using the latest node-fetch module (3.x and above) requires ESM structure on your Node.js server. If you use `require("..")` and not `import .. from ..` style, you are using CJS structure, and you must install version 2 like this: `npm install node-fetch@2`. Now you can include it like in this answer: `const fetch = require('node-fetch')`

Answer (score 1):

With the following code you can make concurrent API calls within an endpoint using Node.js + Express:

```js
const [
      LoMasNuevo, LoMasVisto, TeRecomendamos, Categorias,
    ] = await Promise.all([
      numerosController.getLoMasNuevo(),
      numerosController.getLoMasVisto(),
      numerosController.getRecomendaciones(),
      categoriasController.getCategorias(),
    ]);
```

Inside every get function you can make an axios request like this:

```js
const params = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://development.api.yodlee.com/ysl/transactions',
    headers: {
        'Api-Version': '1.1',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${tokenuser}`,
    },
};

const data = await axios(params);
return data;
```

Answer (score 1):

**In 2022**

In Node.js:

```
const fetch = (...args) => import('node-fetch').then(({ default: fetch }) =>
    fetch(...args));

app.get('/checkDobleAPI', async (req, res) => {
    try {

        const apiResponse = await fetch(
            'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'
        )
        const apiResponseJson = await apiResponse.json()

        console.log(apiResponseJson)
        res.send('Running ')
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        res.status(500).send('Something went wrong')
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

- You can use [Express](https://expressjs.com/) to build a API as your idea
- Then you can call api by using `axios` package.
- In addition, you can build `link` to receive request and send response by using [Router](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) of ExpressJS